# Geodjango query to GeoJSON - TypeError: "User" is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, json, typeerror, geodjango, geojson

I get a GeoQuerySet with all my geometric objects when I do

```
qs = Table.objects.select_related().all()
type(qs)
class 'django.contrib.gis.db.models.query.GeoQuerySet'
qs.values()
[{'geom': <MultiPoint object at 0x7f5ce50fc400>, 'id': 2,
'network_id': None, 'user_id': 1, 'name': 'DJANGO', 'lib_type_id': 1,
...
```

Then I make it a GeoJSON format to put into my html:

```
properties = Table._meta.get_all_field_names()
djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties = properties)
geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
geoj.encode(djf.decode(qs))
```

And i get the error:

```
TypeError: <User: username> is not JSON serializable
```

The username in question IS a ForeignKey and IS a CharField.
What do I have to change to make it serializable ?
Thanks

Comment: You're using vectorformats, which I'm unfamiliar with, but: failure to encode as JSON with a TypeError comes from the data not being in the list of native JSON types. Both integer (foreign key) and string (CharField) ARE serializable. Typical issues come from trying to serialize, say, decimals or sets. I suspect you may have a set there. Of course, querystring objects as such are also not serializable (which is why you usually serialize list(qs)) but vectorformats should take care of that. I'd:
1. reduce properties to investigate what throws the error
2. figure out what type causes the error

Comment: @chryss, thanks for the advice. The problem comes from the foreign key object. I used the to_string=False option of the encode() function, so it passes. My GeoJSON looks like that: `{'crs': None, 'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPoint', 'coordinates': ((3.542531211123772, 43.67105769726195),)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': 2, 'properties': {'author': <User: user>, 'name': ...` What type is <User: user> ? How can i make it serializable?